# python3.4: pylirc module not loaded although is installed on my system

Tags: python-3.4

**Hello!**
pylirc cannot be found during import in python3 scripts. But for python2 it works.
I use pip3 to install pylirc because my Linux distribution has no package pylirc for python3. But it has for python2.
Is that a bug somewhere in python3? Do you think there is a workaround?

```
> python3 -c 'import pylirc' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'pylirc'

> lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description:    Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa
Release:    17.3
Codename:   rosa


> sudo pip3 install pylirc2            
Downloading/unpacking pylirc2
  Downloading pylirc2-0.1.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/pylirc2/setup.py) egg_info for package pylirc2

Installing collected packages: pylirc2
  Running setup.py install for pylirc2
    building 'pylircmodule' extension
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c pylircmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/pylircmodule.o
    pylircmodule.c: In function ‘initpylirc’:
    pylircmodule.c:272:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘Py_InitModule’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         (void) Py_InitModule("pylirc", pylircMethods);
         ^
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/pylircmodule.o -llirc_client -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/pylircmodule.cpython-34m.so

Successfully installed pylirc2
Cleaning up...

> find /usr/local/lib/python3.4/ -name '*pylirc*'
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pylircmodule.cpython-34m.so
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pylirc2-0.1.egg-info

> strace python3 -c 'import pylirc'
...
open("<string>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("<string>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/python3.4/<string>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu/<string>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/<string>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/<string>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/<string>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "ImportError: No module named 'py"..., 38ImportError: No module named 'pylirc'
```

As you can see from strace python does not try finding pylirc in its paths. And it is strange (or it is not?). Somehow python is finding *< string >* instead of something pylirc.
What the magic happens here? :-)

more information:
python3 -v key shows me additional information

```
...
Python 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2224, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'pylirc'
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems pylirc c module does not compatible with python3. Because pylirc does not call PyModule_Create() as describe here https://docs.python.org/3/howto/cporting.html.
The code of pylirc https://github.com/offlinehacker-playground/pylirc2/blob/master/pylircmodule.c

Comment: here is I posted how to patch https://github.com/offlinehacker-playground/pylirc2/issues/3